# iOS getting notify when the device lost/obtain connection

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've to get notified when the device lost or obtain connection and I have to show an alert "Device is going offline" or "Device is going online"
It's possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use Reachability ! here it is https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Answer (score 1):

use *Reachability* , the apple provide the default function for get the network status , try the following [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) , in here you get the sample code also

**choice no-2**

the following [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-detecting-network-changes-with-reachability--mobile-18299) helps you for do the work in step by step and you can get the status also

**choice no --3**

create the custom `NSObject` class and follow the details

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SCNetworkReachability.h>


typedef enum {
IOSDeviceTypeIphone          = 1,
IOSDeviceTypeIpad            = 2,
IOSDeviceTypeIpodTouch       = 3,
} IOSDeviceType;


@interface OUTTDeviceUtility : NSObject

+(id) sharedInstance;

+ (BOOL)checkConnection:(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags*)flags;
+ (BOOL)connectedToNetwork;
+ (BOOL)connectedToWiFi;
@end
```

**.m file**

```
#import "OUTTDeviceUtility.h"
#import <sys/types.h>
#import <sys/socket.h>
#import <sys/sysctl.h>
#import <sys/time.h>
#import <netinet/in.h>
#import <net/if_dl.h>
#import <netdb.h>
#import <errno.h>
#import <arpa/inet.h>
#import <unistd.h>
#import <ifaddrs.h>

@implementation OUTTDeviceUtility

+(id)sharedInstance{
static OUTTDeviceUtility* deviceUtilInstance = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    deviceUtilInstance = [[OUTTDeviceUtility alloc] init];
});

return deviceUtilInstance;
}

+ (BOOL)checkConnection:(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags*)flags
{
struct sockaddr_in zeroAddress;
bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));
zeroAddress.sin_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
zeroAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

SCNetworkReachabilityRef defaultRouteReachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(NULL, (struct sockaddr*)&zeroAddress);
BOOL didRetrieveFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, flags);
CFRelease(defaultRouteReachability);

if(!didRetrieveFlags)
    return NO;
return YES;
}

 + (BOOL)connectedToNetwork
{
SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
if(![OUTTDeviceUtility checkConnection:&flags])
    return NO;

BOOL isReachable = flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable;
BOOL needsConnection = flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired;

return (isReachable && !needsConnection) ? YES : NO;
}

+ (BOOL)connectedToWiFi
{
SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
if(![OUTTDeviceUtility checkConnection:&flags])
    return NO;

BOOL isReachable = flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable;
BOOL needsConnection = flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired;
BOOL cellConnected = flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsTransientConnection;

return (isReachable && !needsConnection && !cellConnected) ? YES : NO;
}

@end
```

accessing like

```
 if(![OUTTDeviceUtility connectedToNetwork] && ![OUTTDeviceUtility connectedToWiFi])
{

 // do your stuff

}
else
{
  // show the error
 }
```